# FCM Push not working on Android 8.0, Oreo

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

On my devices below android 8.0 (Oreo), FCM push working fine. But on Oreo custom sound totally not working, even when the app is on foreground, notification not showing to the status bar.

```
{
    "to" : "fcm_token",
    "notification" : {
            "priority" : "high",
            "title": "Greetings!",
            "body" : "Hope you are enjoying the day.",
            "sound" : "custom_sound"
    }
}
```

And the configuration for FCM is,

```
Uri soundUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + "/" +R.raw.custom_sound);

String CHANNEL_ID = getPackageName();
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_logo)
                    .setContentTitle(title)
                    .setContentText(body)
                    .setAutoCancel(false)
                    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                    .setSound(soundUri);
```

I don't know what I'm missing. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Check about about Notification Channels

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Firebase SDK greater than 10.2.6 and set the notification channel as described [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#manifest), see changelog about 10.2.6 [here](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android).